# I am trying to make a multi select search-able drop-down , But am getting an error in form-group definition

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement multi select 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search but it gives me an formgroup error

//This is my Template Class

```
<div class="main-content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="">
                <div class="card-header card-header-danger">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Edit User</h4>
                    <p class="card-category">Please enter details to edit user</p>
                   <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="formError">{{textStatus}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form [formGroup]="userEditForm">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input matInput required placeholder="First Name" type="text" formControlName="firstName"
                                           [(ngModel)]="data.user.firstName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.firstName.errors }">
                                  <div class="custom-alert" *ngIf="frm.firstName.errors">
                                      First Name is required.
                                    </div>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" type="text" formControlName="lastName"
                                           [(ngModel)]="data.user.lastName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.lastName.errors }">
                                  <div class="custom-alert" *ngIf="frm.lastName.errors">
                                      Last Name is required.
                                    </div>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                      <input matInput placeholder="User Id" formControlName="userId"
                                         [(ngModel)]="data.user.userId" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.emailId.errors }">

                                    <div  class="custom-alert" *ngIf="frm.userId.errors">
                                      UserID is required.
                                    </div>



                                </mat-form-field>

                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Email Id" type="text" formControlName="emailId"
                                           [(ngModel)]="data.user.emailId" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.emailId.errors }">
                                    <div class="custom-alert" *ngIf="frm.emailId.errors">
                                      Email Id is required.
                                    </div>
                                </mat-form-field>

                               <!-- <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <mat-select placeholder="{{firstSelected.roleName}}"
                                                formControlName="newRoleAssigned" [(ngModel)]="firstSelected">

                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">
                                            {{role.roleName}}
                                        </mat-option>

                                    </mat-select>

                                </mat-form-field>-->

                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <mat-select formControlName="MultiRoleCtrl" placeholder="Assign Role" [multiple]="true" #multiSelect>
                                        <ngx-mat-select-search [placeholderLabel]="'Search Role...'" [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No Matching Roles Found'" [formControl]="MultiRoleFilterCtrl">
                                            <mat-icon ngxMatSelectSearchClear>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </ngx-mat-select-search>
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let role of filteredRoles | async" [value]="role.roleName">
                                            {{role.roleName}}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>

                                <span>Gender*</span><mat-radio-group  class="v-space" [value]="gender" (change)="genderSelect($event)" required [(ngModel)]="data.user.userDetails.gender" name="radioGender">

                                  <mat-radio-button class="h-space " value="Male" >Male</mat-radio-button>
                                  <mat-radio-button class="h-space " value="Female" >Female</mat-radio-button>
                                  <mat-radio-button class="h-space " value="Others">Others</mat-radio-button>
                                </mat-radio-group>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group" *ngFor="let address of addressArr">

                          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                          <p class="card-category">Edit your  Address</p>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input matInput placeholder="Block Name" type="text" formControlName="blockName" [(ngModel)]="address.blockName">
                                 </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                     <input matInput placeholder="Block Number" type="text" formControlName="blockNumber" [(ngModel)]="address.blockNumber">
                                 </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                     <input matInput placeholder="Street" type="text" formControlName="street" [(ngModel)]="address.street">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                     <input matInput placeholder="City" type="text" formControlName="city" [(ngModel)]="address.city">
                               </mat-form-field> 
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                     <input matInput placeholder="Country" type="text" formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="address.country">
                                 </mat-form-field>  
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="address.type == 'home'">
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                     <input matInput placeholder="Pincode" type="text" formControlName="pincode" [(ngModel)]="address.pincode">
                                 </mat-form-field>  
                            </div>

                        </div>



                        <button type="submit" cdkFocusInitial (click)="onCancel()" class="btn btn-link pull-left"> 
                            Cancel 
                        </button>

                        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" cdkFocusInitial (click)="onSubmit()"
                                class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                            Save Changes
                        </button>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

//This is My component class

```
public MultiRoleFilterCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
public filteredRoles: ReplaySubject<Role[]> = new ReplaySubject<Role[]>(1);
private _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
@ViewChild('multiSelect') multiSelect: MatSelect;

public userDetails: UserDetails = new UserDetails();
public roles: Role[] = [];




constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            public toastr: ToastrManager,
            public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogEditUser>,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogEditData, public appEditUserService: EditUserService, public appGetRoleService: GetRoleService, private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef, private router: Router) {
}

get frm() {
    return this.userEditForm.controls;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.gender = this.data.user.userDetails.gender;
    this.userDetails.gender = this.gender;
    this.addressArr = this.data.user.address;
    console.log(this.addressArr);

    this.userEditForm = new FormGroup({
        'firstName': new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4)
        ]),
        'lastName': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'emailId': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'userId': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        'gender': new FormControl(this.data.gender, Validators.required),
        'blockName': new FormControl(''),
        'blockNumber': new FormControl(''),
        'street': new FormControl(''),
        'city': new FormControl(''),
        'country': new FormControl(''),
        'pincode': new FormControl(''),
        'type': new FormControl(''),
        'MultiRoleCtrl': new FormControl(''),
        //'MultiRoleFilterCtrl': new FormControl('')
    });



    this.appGetRoleService.getRoles().pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
        this.roles = data;
        },
        error => {
            //console.log(error);
        });


    this.MultiRoleFilterCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.filterRolesMulti();
        });
}


private filterRolesMulti() {
    if (!this.roles) {
        return;
    }

    let search = this.MultiRoleFilterCtrl.value;
    //console.log("the search value is "+search);
    if (!search) {
        this.filteredRoles.next(this.roles.slice());
        return;
    } else {
        search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    // filter the banks
    this.filteredRoles.next(
        this.roles.filter(role => role.roleName.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );
}
```

The Expected result is a dropdown menu with check boxes

[Multi Select DropDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zurmY.png)

https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove 'ngModel' from your inputs. For example you have:

```
<input matInput required placeholder="First Name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" [(ngModel)]="data.user.firstName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.firstName.errors }">
```

But there is no need to use `[(ngModel)]` is you already use `formControlName` as it bind to form control's value anyway.

```
<input matInput required placeholder="First Name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && frm.firstName.errors }">
```

is enough

Comment: The error seems to be solved but the dropdown still doesnt work , can you plz help me with that?

Comment: @HarshNagalla what error do you get? what does not work?